# "Видимость" приложения в Google Play (GP)

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Что сделать, чтобы приложение стало видно в GP? Я загрузил APK файл в Google Play, добавил скриншоты, описание приложения, нажал на кнопку опубликовать. Статус изменился как опубликованный. В консоли разработчика показывают, что приложение поддерживается более чем на 1500 устройств (свое я в том числе нашел). Однако в GP я не могу найти своего приложения, в поиск забиваю название, не находит. Как быть, чтоб приложение стало видно для пользователей?

Comment: кнопочку "сохранить" после "опубликовать" нажали? :)

Comment: да нажимал!

Comment: Может задали только для определенных стран, а свою забыли включить в список?

Answer (score 4):

Еще не проиндексировано поэтому в поиске не видно. Чтобы найти свое приложение напрямую забейте в браузере строчку типа:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<my application package name>
```

Comment: пишет Запрошенный URL не найден на этом сервере. А как долго обычно индексируется?

Comment: Максимум час-два. Если до сих пор нет, значит беда...

Comment: До сих пор нет.(( причина в чем может быть?

Comment: покажи строку адреса =)

Comment: @Gorets ты полагаешь что он так и пишет `id=<my application name>` без указания реального имени пакета? LoL ))

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в редактировании публикации вы убрали галочку для вашего города и оно не показывается для вас.